# Remove sshd identification string

Tags: ssh

When I do nmap scan on SSH port I got

```
22/tcp open ssh OpenSSH 8.2p1 Ubuntu 4ubuntu0.3 (Ubuntu Linux; protocol 2.0)
```

Is it possible to modify SSH identification string or hide it?

Answer (score 2):

This identification string is probably returned by SSH service itself. Try this:

```
echo "blah" | nc YOUR.SERVER.ADDRESS 22
```

This gives response somewhat similar to this:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
Invalid SSH identification string.
```

Unfortunately this is a string embedded inside `sshd` binary. You've got few options:

- Check whether your distro allows specific compile flags for sshd package to remove version banner
- Some distributions, like Debian, allows you to try option like this one: `DebianBanner no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. This is strongly distribution specific
- Hacky one solution. Use `strings` on `sshd` binary to find what strings matches the returned one. After that prepare backup of your current binary and edit it with `hexedit`. Caution: This might end up not being able to ssh onto your server if you try to run modified binary and something goes wrong. Be careful and make sure you've got fallback plan.

Do not tamper with it too much as this identification string is a part of protocol and despite `nc` showing changed string, you might end up with client refusing to connect because string not being properly formatted according to http://www.openssh.com/txt/rfc4253.txt

Comment: Confirmed, `DebianBanner no` also suppresses the Ubuntu identifier (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS). Running that through `nmap -sV -p22 localhost` gets me `22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 8.2p1 (protocol 2.0)` with no indication of Ubuntu, which is the exact same string I get on my Debian 11 box (after similarly disabling DebianBanner).

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed 's/SSH-%d.%d-%.100s%s%s/SSH-%d.%d-OpenSSH___/' /usr/sbin/sshd > modifiedsshd
```

Check that they're still the same size but not the same binary. If they're still the same binary (cmp returns 0) then

```sh
strings /usr/sbin/sshd | grep SSH-
```

to find the correct `printf()` format that your version of SSH is using. The key is that the before and after strings you give to `sed` must be exactly the same length.

It should go without saying, but keep a backup of your `sshd` binary somewhere and try this out first on a machine you have local access to in case something goes wrong.